# Scoring a Deck of Cards

Tags: c++

So i have this particular problem, and need to determine a winning hand. I have posted my code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Card .h"

char * ValueNames[13] = {
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten",
    "Jack",
    "Queen",
    "King",
    "Ace"
};

void Display(const Card & C)
{
    cout << (char)C.Suit << ' ' << ValueNames[C.Value] << endl;
}

void InitDeck(Card Deck[])
{
    int     i;
    Suits   S;
    Values  V;

    srand(time(0)); 
    i = 0;
    for (S = Hearts; S <= Spades; S = (Suits)(S + 1))
        for (V = Two; V <= Ace; V = (Values)(V + 1))
        {
            Deck[i].Suit = S;
            Deck[i].Value = V;
            i++;
        }
}

void SortHand(Card Hand[])
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     CardOne;
    int     CardTwo;
    Card    Temp;



    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        CardOne = 0;
        CardTwo = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            if (Hand[CardOne].Value > Hand[CardTwo].Value)
            {
                Temp = Hand[CardOne];
                Hand[CardOne] = Hand[CardTwo];
                Hand[CardTwo] = Temp;
            }
            else;

            CardOne++;
            CardTwo++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (Hand[3].Value > Hand[4].Value)
    {
        Temp = Hand[3];
        Hand[3] = Hand[4];
        Hand[4] = Temp;
    }
    if (Hand[2].Value > Hand[3].Value)
    {
        Temp = Hand[2];
        Hand[2] = Hand[3];
        Hand[3] = Temp;
    }

    if (Hand[1].Value > Hand[2].Value)
    {
        Temp = Hand[1];
        Hand[1] = Hand[2];
        Hand[2] = Temp;
    }
    if (Hand[0].Value > Hand[1].Value)
    {
        Temp = Hand[0];
        Hand[0] = Hand[1];
        Hand[1] = Temp;
    }

}

void ShowDeck(const Card Deck[])
{
    int     i;

    for (i = 0; i < NumCardsInDeck; i++)
        Display(Deck[i]);
}

void ShowHand(Card Deck[])
{
    int     i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Display(Deck[i]);
}

void Shuffle(Card Deck[])
{
    int     CardOne;
    int     CardTwo;
    Card    Temp;

    for (CardOne = 0; CardOne <NumCardsInDeck; CardOne++)
    {
        CardTwo = rand() % NumCardsInDeck;
        Temp = Deck[CardOne];
        Deck[CardOne] = Deck[CardTwo];
        Deck[CardTwo] = Temp;
    }
}

void Deal(Card Deck[])
{
    int     CardOne;
    int     CardTwo;
    Card    Temp;

    for (CardOne = 0; CardOne < 5; CardOne++)
    {
        CardTwo = rand() % 5;
        Temp = Deck[CardOne];
        Deck[CardOne] = Deck[CardTwo];
        Deck[CardTwo] = Temp;
    }
}

bool    HighestCard(Card Hand[])
{
    if (Hand[0].Value != Hand[1].Value && Hand[0].Value != Hand[2].Value && Hand[0].Value != Hand[3].Value
        && Hand[0].Value != Hand[4].Value && Hand[1].Value != Hand[2].Value && Hand[1].Value != Hand[3].Value &&
        Hand[1].Value != Hand[4].Value && Hand[2].Value != Hand[3].Value && Hand[2].Value != Hand[4].Value && Hand[3].Value != Hand[4].Value)
    {
        return true;
        cout << "The High Card " << endl;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool    OnePair(Card Hand[])
{
    if ((Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[0].Value != Hand[2].Value) ||
        (Hand[1].Value == Hand[2].Value && Hand[1].Value != Hand[3].Value) ||
        (Hand[2].Value == Hand[3].Value && Hand[2].Value != Hand[4].Value) ||
        Hand[3].Value == Hand[4].Value)
    {
        return true;
        cout << "One Pair" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 16);

    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsTwoPair(Card Hand[])
{
    if ((Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[2].Value == Hand[3].Value) || (Hand[1].Value == Hand[2].Value && Hand[3].Value == Hand[4].Value) || (Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[3].Value == Hand[4].Value))
    {
        return true;
        cout << "Two Pair" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 17);
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsThreeOfAKind(Card Hand[])
{
    if ((Hand[0].Value == Hand[2].Value) || (Hand[1].Value == Hand[3].Value) || (Hand[2].Value == Hand[4].Value))
    {
        return true;
        cout << "Three of a Kind" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 18;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsFourOfAKind(Card Hand[])
{
    if ((Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[0].Value == Hand[2].Value && Hand[0].Value == Hand[3].Value) || (Hand[1].Value == Hand[2].Value && Hand[1].Value == Hand[3].Value && Hand[1].Value == Hand[4].Value))
    {
        return true;
        cout << "Four of a Kind" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 22);
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsStraight(Card Hand[])
{
    if (Hand[1].Value == Hand[0].Value + 1 && Hand[2].Value == Hand[1].Value + 1 && Hand[3].Value == Hand[2].Value + 1 && Hand[4].Value == Hand[3].Value + 1)
    {
        return true;
        cout << "Straight" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 19);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
bool IsFullHouse(Card Hand[])
{
    if ((Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[0].Value == Hand[2].Value && Hand[3].Value == Hand[4].Value) || (Hand[0].Value == Hand[1].Value && Hand[2].Value == Hand[3].Value && Hand[2].Value == Hand[4].Value))

    {
        return true;
        cout << "Full House" << endl;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsRoyalFlush(Card Hand[])
{
    if (Hand[1].Value == Hand[0].Value + 1 && Hand[2].Value == Hand[1].Value + 1 && Hand[3].Value == Hand[2].Value + 1 && Hand[4].Value == Hand[3].Value + 1)
    {
        return true;
        cout << "Straight" << endl;
        //scoring = (scoring + 19);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Card .h"

int main()
{
    Card    Deck[52];
    Card    Hands[4][5];
    int     i, j;
    const int StartingRank = 2;
    const int NumRanks = 13;


    InitDeck(Deck);
    cout << "\t The deck starts as " << endl;
    ShowDeck(Deck);
    Shuffle(Deck);
    cout << "\t After shuffling it is" << endl;
    ShowDeck(Deck);


    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Hands[0][i] = Deck[j];
        j++;
    }
    SortHand(Hands[0]);
    cout << "Hand 1 is: " << endl;
    if (HighestCard(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tHighest Card" << endl;
    if (OnePair(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tOne Pair" << endl;
    if (IsThreeOfAKind(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tThree of a kind" << endl;
    if (IsTwoPair(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tTwo Pair" << endl;
    if (IsFourOfAKind(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tFour of a Kind" << endl;
    if (IsFullHouse(Hands[0]))
        cout << "\tFull House" << endl;
    if (IsStraight(Hands[0]))
        cout << " \tStraight" << endl;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Display(Hands[0][i]);
    }



    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Hands[1][i] = Deck[j];
        j++;
    }
    SortHand(Hands[1]);
    cout << "Hand 2 is: " << endl;
    if (HighestCard(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tHighest Card" << endl;
    if (OnePair(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tOne Pair" << endl;
    if (IsThreeOfAKind(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tThree of a kind" << endl;
    if (IsTwoPair(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tTwo Pair" << endl;
    if (IsFourOfAKind(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tFour of a Kind" << endl;
    if (IsFullHouse(Hands[1]))
        cout << "\tFull House" << endl;
    if (IsStraight(Hands[1]))
        cout << " \tStraight" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Display(Hands[1][i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Hands[2][i] = Deck[j];
        j++;
    }
    SortHand(Hands[2]);
    cout << "Hand 3 is: " << endl;
    if (HighestCard(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tHighest Card" << endl;
    if (OnePair(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tOne Pair" << endl;
    if (IsThreeOfAKind(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tThree of a kind" << endl;
    if (IsTwoPair(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tTwo Pair" << endl;
    if (IsFourOfAKind(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tFour of a Kind" << endl;
    if (IsFullHouse(Hands[2]))
        cout << "\tFull House" << endl;
    if (IsStraight(Hands[2]))
        cout << " \tStraight" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Display(Hands[2][i]);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Hands[3][i] = Deck[j];
        j++;
    }
    SortHand(Hands[3]);
    cout << "Hand 4 is: " << endl;
    if (HighestCard(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tHighest Card" << endl;
    if (OnePair(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tOne Pair" << endl;
    if (IsThreeOfAKind(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tThree of a kind" << endl;
    if (IsTwoPair(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tTwo Pair" << endl;
    if (IsFourOfAKind(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tFour of a Kind" << endl;
    if (IsFullHouse(Hands[3]))
        cout << "\tFull House" << endl;
    if (IsStraight(Hands[4]))
            cout << " \tStraight" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Display(Hands[3][i]);
    }

}
```

I sort of have started a scoring method for this program. How would i finish it to determine a winning hand? If the rest of my code is needed, i will post it.

Thanks!

Comment: Off topic: Tonnes of duplicated code in there just screaming to be made into a function. For your sorting, consider saving some time and trouble and using `std::sort`.

Comment: On topic, I'm having trouble finding where you start the scoring, let alone how you are doing it.

Comment: Yeah C++ is so far my least favorite class, and I could have probably made the code overall cleaner by going different routes in some areas, but i got this to work so i'm going with it lol.

Comment: I should rephrase, I assigned a score to each type of hand, two pair = 18, one pair = 17 etc. Based on a suggestion for a fellow classmate, i just don't see how i can put then into writable code to determine the winning hand.

Comment: `void main` has never been valid, and most compilers don't accept it. This makes it less easy for readers to try your code, and teaches an ungood convention to newbies. Please don't post code with `void main`. Fixed that for you.

Comment: **–1** Tons of code and no explanation.

Comment: Professor has taught us to use void main the entire semester lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define an **int** value for each combination according to their order. HighestCard - 0, OnePair - 1, ...
2. Find out what combination does each hand has. You already did it with your if statements. Just store the corresponding values somewhere.
3. Sort cards in each hand by their ranks. Suits are no longer needed as all combinations are already defined.
4. Sort hands. First compare hand combination values. In case they are equal then compare cards starting from the highest one by one.
5. The winning hand is the first (last) in the sorted container.

Also it might be useful to check out [this code](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?92wpizwskbni) for optimized definition of combinations.